# Google Play Game Services and 64bit x86 support

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, google-play-services

How do I implement `x86_64` support for *Google Play Game Services C++*? The provided libraries in version 3.01 (latest version as for now) only contains *arm64-v8a*, *armeabi-v7a* and *x86*. I.e no *x86_64* library. I've tried using the x86 library with my x86_64 build, but it does not link.

Anyone knows how to handle this!?

Note; as of February 2020 Google Play requires all apps to support 64bit.

Comment: I have no experience with android, but from memory though the following link might be informative (even if you don't use/know Qt): https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/06/28/comply-upcoming-requirements-google-play

Answer (score 1):

We should expect a x86_64 update for the SDK unless Google chooses to ditch it altogether. In the short run, you don't really need such build. It's critical to have 64-bit ARM binaries for Play Store, but will your game be played on Chromebook?

Comment: Chromebook is approximately half a procent of the total share, so it's not nessesary although quite annoying. I have arm64, arm and x86 in the apk right now, and Google still complains there is no x86_64 build. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you worry about their complaint, remove x86 for a while.